# JAR classpath and external jars

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

I actualy have 2 problems

I use eclipse -> export project to generate a jar file for my simple desktop (GUI) program
It generates a jar file and an ant script.

first problem: 
the generated jar works fine when double-clicked.
When I use the generated ant script to generate the jar
by myself, it doesn't work.
What can be wrong with a target like this (assuming that all dependencies are met)

```
 <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="G:/dev/myproj/myproj.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="view.myproj"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value=". myproj_lib/grouplayout.jar"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="G:/dev/myproj/bin"/>
        </jar>
        <delete dir="G:/dev/myproj/myproj_lib"/>
        <mkdir dir="G:/dev/myproj/myproj_lib"/>
        <copy file="G:/dev/.metadata/.plugins/org.dyno.visual.swing/layoutext/grouplayout.jar" todir="G:/dev/myproj/myproj"/>
    </target>
```

//**nevemind**
//Second problem:
//when I double click on the auto-generated jar file the program launches and works fine.
//when I do java myjar from the command-line I get main class not found exception..
//weird huh?

Comment: You need to give us the error your getting fro problem1. And problem 2, what's the exact java command your using? Are you using java -jar?

Comment: damn it! I feel so stupid! I forgot the -jar
but the first problem remains
the self-generated jar from the auto generated ant script
does not respond to clicks.. nothing happens

Comment: What error message are you getting when you run the Ant script?

Comment: none! ant script runs OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you take the JAR files generated the two ways, use the `jar` command to expand them into temporary directories, and then use `diff` in recursive mode to compare them.

However, I suspect that @Pace has put his finger on the problem; i.e. that you are using relative paths in the `Class-Path` manifest entry and this is liable to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

`java -jar <jar name>` is the proper way to execute a jar.

Answer (score 0):

The ant target is creating a manifest with a classpath attribute.  If you look at those paths you'll notice that they are relative to the current directory.  When you execute java -jar from the command line are you in the...

```
G:/dev/myproj
```

...directory?